# Small unwanted delay loading icons with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I've a list of installed applications that I display in a RecyclerView.
The application icon is stored in a byte array and I use Glide to bind it to an ImageView using:

```
    Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
            .load(application.getIcon())
            .into(icon);
```

The problem is that it **tooks about 500-700 ms** for the icon to be displayed, then it appears in a nice and smooth way. But I don't want that delay nor want to fallback to a placeholder.

If I change Glide code for direct loading (in main application thread) then the icons appear **instantly**:

```
    byte[] image = application.getIcon();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length,options);
    icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But the problem is that If I scroll fast the list sometimes there are some little glitches.

Is there something that I can do to load the icons faster with Glide?
I've tried with **.dontAnimate()** and **.dontTransform()** but I haven't seen any differences. What can I do to load the images instantly and get similar results than loading directly in main thread?